# Looping through list to create SQL Query

Tags: c#, sql

I have a list of variables which I need to convert to LIKE statements in SQL. The final query should look like the following:

```sql
...
WHERE ([TraceableItem].[IdentificationNo] LIKE N'%015558' 
       OR [TraceableItem].[IdentificationNo] LIKE N'%123456' 
       OR [TraceableItem].[IdentificationNo] LIKE N'%654321')
...
```

Below is my code to do it, but I feel it is fairly inefficient / redundant. Especially features like having a bool for firstLoop, and constantly checking for items already existing. I would be very grateful for a code review and tips on how to improve - I'm fairly rusty on C#

```cs
string queryInsertString = "([TraceableItem].[IdentificationNo] LIKE ";
string lastBatchNo = batchnos.Last();
List<string> alreadyAdded = new List<string>();
bool firstLoop = true;
foreach(string item in batchnos)
            {
    string splitItem = item.Split('/')[1];
    if (!alreadyAdded.Contains(item)){
        if (!firstLoop)
        {
            queryInsertString += " OR [TraceableItem].[IdentificationNo] LIKE N'%" + splitItem + "'";
        } else
        {
            queryInsertString += "N'%" + splitItem + "'";
            firstLoop = false;
        }
        alreadyAdded.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're lacking some of the context here - when reviewing, we want to see the complete program or function, including the definitions of the identifiers in scope (e.g. `batchnos` in this question).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [String.Join](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Join_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_String__) makes this kind of string operation a breeze:

```
// DON'T USE THIS - SQL INJECTION
string predicates = string.Join(" OR ", 
        batchNos.Select(item => item.Split('/')[1])
                .Distinct()
                .Select(splitItem => $"[TraceableItem].[IdentificationNo] LIKE N'%{splitItem}'"));
string queryInsertString = "(" + predicates + ")";
```

You'll notice the all capital warning not to use that code. It's not just because I haven't even checked if it compiles/works, it's because this kind of thing introduces a SQL Injection Vulnerability.

What you need to do is read up on using SqlParameters in C#. You'll want to generate SQL that looks more like:

```
[TraceableItem].[IdentificationNo] LIKE @param1 OR [TraceableItem].[IdentificationNo] LIKE @param2
```

You then need to create a SqlParameter instance for each one and add that to the SqlCommand before you execute it. That's assuming you're using Ado.Net, if you're using a framework you'll have to look up the right way of doing it in the one you're using.

The danger is that if someone passes a batch number of `"a/'); delete from Users; --"`, you'll end up creating a query that looks like:

```
WHERE ([TraceableItem].[IdentificationNo] LIKE N''); delete from Users; -- ...
```

You do not want a user to be able to do that!

Comment: Thank you very much. SQL Injection wasn't something I'd thought about

Answer (score 4):

Your SQL query is never going to be efficient because it has wildcard at the start, and is not Sargable (`LIKE N'%015558'`).

Assuming your database allows it, what you should do in this scenario is to create a `PERSISTED` computed SQL column which is set to `REVERSE(IdentificationNo)`, and create an index on that column.

Combine this with the advice from @RobH, and make your query something similar.

```
WHERE [ReversedIdentificationNo] LIKE + splitItem.Reverse() + '%'
```

This way, your query will use an index seek (instead of an index scan) and potentially be magnitudes faster.

EDIT: 
With a variable number of `IdentificationNo` that you intend of searching, you run into a cache pollution issue. For every distinct number of parameters, your SQL engine will *not* be able to reuse an existing query cache plan. This is very common issue when dynamically generating SQL statements (especially without SQL paramters).

To avoid this, you could use a temp table / table type.

`CREATE TYPE Ids AS TABLE ( ID varchar(128) PRIMARY KEY )`

Then, instead of constructing a bunch of `OR` statements, you just insert all your `splitItem` into this temp table. Finally, your query looks something like the following.

```
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM @Ids
    WHERE [ReversedIdentificationNo] LIKE [Id] + '%'
)
```